# How to call the elements of an array inside a loop

Tags: matlab

I want to call the elements of an array inside a loop.

```
function [output]=function_name(channel)

Channel=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

for i=1:9
   res=myfunction(param1,param2,channel)
end
```

Comment: Please look here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html

Comment: This just looks like lack of some basic MATLAB syntax knowledge, please read the MathWorks [getting started guide](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html), in particular the [array indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html) section.

Comment: Thank you.But when I want to call ,for instance,function_name(6),that doesn't work;because in myfunction(param1,param2,channel) here channel need to be a number.How can I fix it?

Comment: That comment isn't clear, you say you're passing the input `channel = 6`, and then getting an error because `channel` needs to be a number? [Edit] your question to include a [mcve], with example inputs and expected outputs, or it is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have to tell Matlab which element of your `channel` array it should use for each iteration. So what you need to do is something like this:

```
channel=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
res = zeros(1,7);

for i=1:7
   res(i)=myfunction(param1,param2,channel(i));
end
```

Please also be aware that Matlab is case sensitive. So `Channel` and `channel` is not the same. Also I changed `res` to an array and assign the function output to `res(i)` because otherwise only the very last output of your function will be stored in the `res` variable.

And finally your `channel` array only contains seven elements. So you can only loop to 7 in this case.